# integrate sin(x)cos(x) using trig identity.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Book tells me the answer is:

$$ \int \sin(x)\cos(x) dx = \frac{1}{2} \sin^{2}(x) + C $$

however, I get the result:

$$
\sin(A)\cos(B) = \frac{1}{2} \sin(A-B)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(A+B)
$$

$$ 
\begin{split}
\int \sin(x)\cos(x) dx 
 &= \int \left(\frac{1}{2}\sin(x-x) + \frac{1}{2}\sin(x+x)\right) dx \\
 &= \int \left(\frac{1}{2}\sin(0) + \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)\right) dx \\
 &= \int \left(\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)\right) dx \\
 &= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) +C\\
 &= -\frac{1}{4} \cos(2x) +C
\end{split}
$$

How did the book arrive at the answer $\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x)$?

Comment: $\int \sin 2x\ \text {dx} = -\frac {\cos 2x} {2} + C$ and use the fact that $\cos 2x =1-2{\sin}^2 x.$

Comment: Has your question been answered? If yes, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2x$$
From here you get
$$-\frac{1}{4}\cos(2x) + C = -\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\sin^2 x+C = \frac{1}{2}\sin^2x + C_1$$
where $C_1 = -\frac{1}{4}+C$ is a new constant.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The answers are equivalent. Recall that
$$
\cos (2x) = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x = \left(1-\sin^2 x\right) - \sin^2 x = 1 - 2 \sin^2x
$$

Answer (score 0):

Because
$$\frac{1}{2} \sin^2(x) = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\int \sin 2x\ \text {dx} = -\frac {\cos 2x} {2} + C$ and use the fact that $\cos 2x =1-2{\sin}^2 x.$

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question (“How did the book”, etc.): probably just by inspection (chain rule backwards), or else via the substitution $u=\sin x$, $du = \cos x \, dx$.